# SwiftUI, buttons in horizontal stack not rendering when building project

Tags: button, render, swiftui

For some reason when I 'resume' my code in the preview/canvas pane in SwiftUI I can see my social media buttons show up clearly, however when I run the code by pressing the build button which takes me to the separate simulator I do not see my social media buttons. I have been stuck on this for the past 2 day, not sure if this is a bug with the new SwiftUI or not at this point.

Note: I have a navigationLink called in another page to this current page.

Please see example of the former: [image: canvas/preview pane:Correct]

Please see example of the the incorrect rendering (using command + R): [image: incorrect version when building project]

Please see the actual code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CreateAccountView: View {

@State var username: String = ""
@State var password: String = ""
    @State var passwordVerify: String = ""
@State private var showPassword = false
@State private var showPasswordVerify = false
@State private var current: Int? = nil


var body: some View {

    NavigationView{

        GeometryReader { (deviceSize: GeometryProxy) in

            ZStack {
                //Define a screen color
                LinearGradient (gradient: Gradient(colors:[Color(ColorsSaved.gitLabDark),Color(ColorsSaved.gitLabLight)]),startPoint: .leading,endPoint: .trailing)
                    //Extend the screen to all edges
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                VStack {
                    Text ("Create Account")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding ()

                    Group {
                        HStack {
                            Image ("user")
                                .resizable ()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .padding (10)

                            TextField("Username", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .padding(12)
                                .padding (.leading, -10)
                                .padding(.leading, -3)
                            Spacer ()
                        } .padding (.leading, 10)

                        Spacer ()

                        HStack {
                            Image ("mail")
                                .resizable ()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .padding (10)

                            TextField("Email", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .padding(12)
                                .padding (.leading, -10)
                                .padding(.leading, -3)
                        } .padding (.leading, 10)

                        Spacer()

                        HStack {
                            Image ("phone")
                                .resizable ()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .padding (10)

                            TextField("Phone", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .padding(12)
                                .padding (.leading, -10)
                                .padding(.leading, -3)
                        } .padding (.leading, 10)

                        Spacer()


                        HStack {
                            Image("unlock")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .padding (11)
                            if self.showPassword == true{
                                TextField("Password", text: self.$password)
                                    .padding(12)
                                    .padding (.leading, -10)
                                    .padding(.leading, -3)
                                // .frame(width: 175)// if you want to custom where the lock,passwordm and eye relation
                            } else {
                                SecureField("Password", text: self.$password)
                                    .padding(12)
                                    .padding (.leading, -10)
                                    .padding(.leading, -3)

                            }
                            Button (action: {self.showPassword.toggle()}) {
                                if self.showPassword == true {
                                    Image("eye-unlock")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .padding (11)
                                        .foregroundColor (.secondary)
                                } else {
                                    Image("eye")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .padding (11)
                                        .foregroundColor (.secondary)
                                }

                            }// closes button
                        } .padding(.leading, 10)//close Hstack for lock
                            .padding (.trailing, 10)

                        Spacer()

                        HStack {
                            Image("unlock")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .padding (11)
                            if self.showPasswordVerify == true{
                                TextField("Verify Password", text: self.$passwordVerify)
                                    .padding(12)
                                    .padding (.leading, -10)
                                    .padding(.leading, -3)
                                // .frame(width: 175)// if you want to custom where the lock,passwordm and eye relation
                            } else {
                                SecureField("Verify Password", text: self.$passwordVerify)
                                    .padding(12)
                                    .padding (.leading, -10)
                                    .padding(.leading, -3)

                            }
                            Button (action: {self.showPasswordVerify.toggle()}) {
                                if self.showPasswordVerify == true {
                                    Image("eye-unlock")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .padding (11)
                                        .foregroundColor (.secondary)
                                } else {
                                    Image("eye")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .padding (11)
                                        .foregroundColor (.secondary)
                                }

                            }// closes button
                        } .padding(.leading, 10)//close Hstack for lock
                            .padding (.trailing, 10)


                    }.background(Color.white)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40))
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                        .frame(maxHeight:40, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.leading, 25)
                        .padding (.trailing, 25)




                    VStack (spacing: 2) {
                        Button (action: {print("create Account pressed!!")}) {
                            Text("Create")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding(10)
                                .foregroundColor(.orange)

                                .padding (.leading, 75)
                                .padding(.trailing, 75)


                        } .padding (.leading, 10)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50))
                            .overlay(
                                Capsule(style: .continuous)
                                    .stroke(Color.orange, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2)))
                            .shadow(radius: 10)
                            .frame(maxHeight:40, alignment: .leading)
                        Spacer()
                        Text ("OR")
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)

                        Spacer()

                        Text ("Sign up using social accounts")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                        Spacer ()

                        HStack {
                            Button (action: {print("Facebook Account pressed!!")}) {
                                Image("facebook")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .padding (-3)


                        }
                            Spacer()

                            Button (action: {print("Twitter Account pressed!!")}) {
                                Image("twitter")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                .padding (-3)

                            }
                            Spacer()

                            Button (action: {print("Twitter Account pressed!!")}) {
                                Image("google")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                .padding (-3)


                            }
                        }.padding(.trailing, 45)
                            .padding (.leading, 45)
                            .offset(y: 10)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())//allows buttons to render correclty whilein a navi view

                    }.padding(.top, 40)
                        .offset (y: -10)




                }
                    .offset (y:-50)

            }

        }
    }
}
}

struct CreateAccountView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    CreateAccountView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account that I don't see button images after copied snapshot into my test environment even in Preview. And after replacing their names with images from my project assets they appear and in Preview and in Simulator.

So, I can assume that you've forgotten to add those button images into your target assets catalog.

*BTW, test your layout, which is highly hardcoded, on smaller models as well, because in iPhone 11 (and above) they fit into screen, but for example on iPhone 8 they don't.*

Tested on: Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2 / Simulator iPhone 8 & iPhone 11 Pro